# React native, Debugging a native library?

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio

Suppose there's a RN library which has native (java/swift) code in it.

I'd like to debug this java code, (it seems it has a bug)

How can I set a breakpoint in this native code? I can't find this file in the android-studio

For RN .60+ where there's no explicit link step..

Comment: I am working with extending a native package right now for my additional use cases. I am not sure about breakpoints. But I am editing the Java files inside VS Code, saving and run ```npx react-native run-android``` after every edit. To understand values, I am using ```Log.d("value ", value)``` and checking the value is correct inside Logcat.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LogCat and the Debug Console in Android Studio and Xcode respectively.

As this is only aimed at Android, this answer will focus on LogCat only.

**Getting Logs:**

If you navigate to the native library and find a Java file which specifies a `package` name, you can use this to filter LogCat.

For example, you can use `com.reactnativecommunity.netinfo` if you were debugging [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/netinfo/NetInfoModule.java)

Ensuring that your device and debuggable process is set within LogCat, you can filter out Logs by type, if your library is throwing an Error, filter it by Error and apply the package name to filter out any unwanted logs.

From here you should receive a detailed stack trace which includes the problematic files, from there you can start to debug.

**Debugging:**

Once you've located the problematic files, open it within Android Studio.

Click on the right side, next line number to add a breakpoint.

With the app running, click on the Debug icon and select your app/running process.

[image]

When your breakpoints are hit, Android Studio will pause and allow you to debug.